# Convert Numeric format dates to dates in Oracle

Tags: oracle

This is how my Date column looks like

```
RPT_DT (Data Type is Number)
20180131
20180130
20180129
```

I wanna extract month out of these dates(either Month or mm), and I tried below

```
select extract(month from to_date(Rpt_dt))
from
(
select distinct to_char(to_date(RPT_DT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') Rpt_dt 
from  TABLE_NAME
)
```

I am getting the error "Not a valid month"

Comment: Why do you make a number (or string) to `DATE`, then to `VARCHAR2` and then to `DATE` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(rpt_dt, 'YYYYMMDD')) 
  FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

and I believe you need to modify your query as you did not put the format 'MM/DD/YYYY',

```
select extract(month from to_date(Rpt_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
 from
 (
select distinct to_char(to_date(RPT_DT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') Rpt_dt 
from  TABLE_NAME
 )
```

Comment: @Tpk43 The format was needed. Or alternatively, if the inner query kept it as a `date` then the outer query could just extract the month without any further conversion.

Answer (score 3):

if there is not any particular reason to have a double conversion I would suggest you to handle the problem with this simple query:

```
select substr(to_char(RPT_DT),5,2)from THE_TABLE
```

this query should be more performant since it make only one conversion. in your sample you transform:

- a number to a date
- then a date to a char
- the char again in date
- finally you extract the month

let me know if it help
r.

Answer (score 0):

This back-and-forth conversion is useless. Try this

```
select 
   extract(month from to_date(RPT_DT,'yyyymmdd'))
from  TABLE_NAME;
```